# Find the transpose operator $T^{t}$ in a R vectorial space with the usual scalar product.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

The operator $T:V \to V$ is defined as $T(v) = \langle v,y\rangle z$ with $y,z$ in $V$

Lets check $\langle Tv,v \rangle = \langle v,T^tv \rangle = \langle T^tv,v \rangle$ then $\langle Tv - T^tv,v \rangle = 0$ for all $v$ in $V$ so $T = T^t$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not.

You don't use the fact that $T(v) = \langle v, y \rangle z$. That should be a little bit suspicious since most of the times every part of a problem  is in the statement for a reason.

The flaw in your reasoning is that you are taking the product with the same vector over which $T$ is applied. Under that assumption, every operator would be self-adjoint :(

Enough of criticism. Hint:

$$
\langle T(v), w\rangle = \langle \langle v, y \rangle z, w\rangle = \langle v,y\rangle \langle z,w\rangle = \langle v, \langle z,w\rangle y\rangle = \langle v, f(w) \rangle
$$

Observe that $f$ is a linear operator that can be put in terms of $z$ and $y$ and it's sort of in the position in which you'd expect the $T^t$ to be in the product.

I've assumed in the product manipulations that $V$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-space.